# Restrict submitter as approver in approval process

Tags: approval-process, before-trigger

I know that currently Salesforce does not offer a way to restrict a submitter who can approve their own record if the same user is a part of a queue meant for approving records or if the user is system admin. But, can we have an apex trigger on before update context(for example opportunity object to submit a quote approval request) for this to restrict the admin user to approve the records unanimously? I have tried the ways to capture submitter and approver information from approval process field update, but lacks in trigger code. Can someone help?

There are also scenarios that a submitter can be an approver if they are running users or owner of a record since in my approval process record owners are initial submitters.

Comment: It's possible to fetch approval process metadata in Apex by querying `ProcessInstance` and `ProcessInstanceHistory`. You could query for approvals pending the context user's approval that are tied to the target objects in the Trigger. It should be possible to fetch those with just one query. [Here is the data model for the approval process objects.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_process.htm)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I am also looking at using the processInstance class but also lagging the idea to fetch those items. Could you please help little bit in terms of code on how to get those user ids and compare them? Just initial idea is fine.